# Render the FileField as multiple file input field in the form based on multiple choices field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 models, Product and Document. Document has a FK to Product.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='documents', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to=file_upload_to)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=DOC_TYPE)
```

The Document can have different types (data sheet, whitepaper etc).

So, if I have 3 types of documents I want to see in HTML 3 inputs, each input representing a type:

```
<input name="myFile" type="file">  --> type 1
<input name="myFile" type="file">  --> type 2
<input name="myFile" type="file">  --> type 3
```

1. After the form is submitted, I want somehow to know which type of document was it and then, modify the form and select in code the type

I'm thinking on using a custom widget inheriting from File, and add an attribute in each input, and then in `save` method identify the type

2. Passing 1) what if I want to let the user add multiple documents for each type, and the number will not be equal for each one of type (a type can have 3, another type 1, and the third one none)

The user will not select the type, he will just upload files, based on UI.

See the example image below, the icons/image are the inputs (behind css done)

Each input represent a choice. In reality is just an input file field per but I create 3 for each choice/type. The user can add as many file per type/choice by click an add (plus sign) near the type/choice icon/image(that is in design)

---

[image]

Comment: In your opening sentence you're writing about 2 models: **Product** and **Document**, but in your code example you call your class model `ProductDocument`. You should rethink your design and make the things clearer. Naming is one of the most important issue in software development.

Comment: @cezar there are 2 models, Product and Document; I updated the question (I used ProductDocument, because I have other Document models related to other models than Product)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand exactly what you're after. **(1)** You want us to provide you with the code that will render an input file for each document type, **(2)** you don't know where to start and you need us to give you some pointers or **(3)** you have some code already but it's not working as it should

Comment: @Adelin, I edited the question to be more clear; I want 1) and 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your view that creates the formset:

```
for form in formset:

    form.fields['document'].widget.attrs = {'mytype':'whitepaper'}
```

Then on the POST you capture the attribute to check if that is whitepaper.

Let me know if that works

Comment: I don't need the file type; the document type has nothing to do with the file type; the document type is for example whitepaper or datasheet but can be more. What I want is for each predefined type , for each choice to create a new input element. Behing each input element will have like an identifier for each type, and after form submit, I get this data and assign behind the scene the type/choice.

Comment: So you want to set the type on your form based on the input itself? Input 1 = datasheet, input 2 = whitepaper? etc? if so, use a formfactory and on the save u know that row 1 is datasheet and row 2 is whitepaper

Comment: (I added an image as example). A form factory, can you give a code example. My thought is to do  something on the rendering side (template) and get on save.

Comment: On the formset you can manipulate each form, and maybe add a tag that can be retrieved on the request, what do u think?

Comment: @I can try if you can give me a starting example;I never used a formset this way; in the formset you repeat all form multiple times, I need to repeat only the type/choice. It can work for what I have, I don't know if will be issues in the future adding other fields to the model.